# Django Rest Framework mulitplechoicefield - int not iterable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multiplechoicefield

I am beginning to use and implement the Django Rest Framework and I have an issue with the multiple choice field.

My variable "CHOICES" looks like the following

```
(('0', 'Read Only'), ('5', 'Operator 1'), ('7', 'Operator 2'), ('100', 'Supervisor 1'), ('102', 'Supervisor 2'), ('255', 'Administrator'))
```

and the line that sets the field looks like

```
access = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, allow_blank=False)
```

but I get the following error

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 1348, in to_representation
>       self.choice_strings_to_values.get(six.text_type(item), item) for item in value
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

when going into fields.py and printing the value, it is just a 255

I have tried explicitly iterating the current list and adding the items to a new array, but same problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, I guess I am supposed to just use a "ChoiceField" Instead of a "MultipleChoiceField"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed "MultipleChoiceField" to "ChoiceField" and it works great.
I guess I misunderstood the "MultipleChoiceField"